# Подпись apk приложения

Tags: android

Купил аккаунт разработчика в гугле. Решил залить прогу свою. Но тут куча ошибок с неправильными подписями.

То ему не нравится сертификат выданный командой Android, то ему не нравится, что он просрочен, То ещё что-то не нравится.

Поискал кучу вариантов подписи, нашёл [один верный](http://www.articlecms.in/3874-how-to-sign-android-applications-and-games-apk.html#.T9h0L1LeJGM). Но мне нужен файл .pem, с собственными данными, я нашёл, [как их создавать](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=539911f638c4640f&table=%2Fotvety%2Flabel%3Flid%3D28207fe5555085a3). Но почему-то при выполнении этих действий, при запросе Password я не могу ничего ввести в командной строке. Как быть?? Как создать этот файл и подписать, наконец, приложение?

Answer (score 4):

Все просто. Вам нужно создать свой серфтификат, ибо маркет не принимает дебажный сертификат. Создается он утилитой keytool, которая идет с JDK:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore \
    -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Ну а потом нужно в Eclipse выгрузить апк, подписанный этим сертификатом.
Только когда будете создавать его - пароль запишите себе.

Можно и без эклипс. Утилитами командной строки (android например)

Вообще, для публикации нужны иконки, скрины и много чего еще, поэтому подобные вещи лучше делать походу работы над проектом и лучше в эклипс. Ну у Вас, конечно, другой случай!

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете проект все же создать? Так как автор сказал, что делает он не в эклипсе

Comment: можно и без. Но так головняков поболя будет. Просто командная строка в помощь.

Comment: а зачем для скринов эклипс не понял. С устройства они качественне получается, остальную графику сами делали

Comment: я сказал лишь, что удобнее. Там все под рукой и с графическим интерфейсом.

Comment: Я уже пробовал командной строкой, почему-то когда у меня запрашивают пароль, я не могу его ввести, тупо не вводит символы никакие.

Comment: он вводит. Скорее всего ввод просто не отображен в целях безопасности

Answer (score 2):

[Публикация](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php)

вот по этому плану делал, все нормально загрузилось с 1го раза

Comment: Я делал не в Eclipse, у меня есть только готовый .apk, либо же html-версия, которую у меня почему-то не получается импортировать.

Comment: тогда не знаю, извините

Comment: ты через консоль администратора в гугл плей это делаешь?

Comment: @Gorets вы мне или ТС?

Comment: тс =))))))

Comment: Gorets, да я через консоль админа в гугле плей это делаю, а что ещё как-то можно?

Answer (score 1):

[Подпись apk файла для публикации в android market из Eclipse](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/03/apk-android-market-eclipse.html)

Comment: Ура! Я подписал его! Создал в эклипсе ключ для мнимого проекта, зашёл в свой аккаунт PhoneGap, и туда его загрузил, и теперь все проекты автоматически подписываются моим ключом)

Comment: @chuikoff давайте хвалитесь ссылкой на маркет.