# Что должно быть сделано перед выпуском релиза?

Tags: java, android

Все основные фичи готовы к выпуску и можно опубликовать релиз.

В таком случае нужно указать дату сборки и номер релиза...

Что еще нужно сделать?

Comment: открыть Developer console и нажать на "Добавить приложение" ну и там все заполняйте. Еще можете спросить себя "А оно мне надо". Вопрос точнее пожалуйста, где именно и что нужно Вам еще сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Для публикации приложения вам необходимо создать подписанное приложение.
У Александра Климова есть неплохой подробный мануал о том, как это делается
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php

Также, о подписании приложений есть у ребят на СтартАндроид инструкция 
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/221-urok-123-kak-podpisat-prilozhenie-utility-keytool-i-jarsigner.html

примечание: ранее такая ссылка уже указывалась на StackOverFlow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/119099/194314