# Как подписать новую версию приложения, если у меня сохранился SHA1 от предыдущего приложения

Tags: android

Для того, чтобы выпустить обновление существующего приложения мне нужно, чтобы они были подписаны одинаковыми сертификатами. У версий совпадают названия пакетов и я обновила versionCode и versionName. У меня есть SHA1 от предыдущей версии. Как мне подписать новую версию?

Comment: sha1 вам не поможет, вам нужен сам сертификат.

Comment: Mike, а как он выглядит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA1 вам не поможет, нужен сертификат и приватный ключ от него. Они могут быть в разных форматах (*.cer, *.key, *.pfx, *.p12, *.crx, *.der, *.crt и другие). Ваш приватный ключ находится только у вас, так что восстановить его никак нельзя.

Comment: Zergatul, а если у меня есть приватный ключ и сертификат, как подписать приложение?

Comment: @Anna13 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119093/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-apk-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Zergatul, я всеровно не поняла, мне надо сделать это в Android Studio

Comment: @Anna13 Я это делал последний раз очень давно, я сам не помню тонкостей. Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, и опишите что именно в вас не получается, и вам помогут.